# React get height of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to know the height of a **React Component** inside another React component. I am aware that the height of an element can be reached by calling `this.cmref.current.clientHeight`. I'm looking for something like this:

child component:

```js
const Comp = () =>{
    return(
        <div>some other stuff here</div>
    )
}
export default Comp
```

parent component:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.compref = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidSomething(){
        const height = this.compref.current.clientHeight;
        //which will be undefined
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Comp ref={this.compref} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible and should work with above code.

Comment: @ApplePearPerson It is not working. Are you sure? cause i just tested an ordinary div element and got the correct result but the same thing wont work on a react component.

Comment: Apologies I fell for the same trap you did. I'll add an answer with a working snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to actually ref the div of the child component in order to get the element you want instead of the child component itself. To do this you could pass a function to the child that the child then passes to the div. Working example below:

```js
const Comp = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div ref={props.onRef}>some other stuff here</div>
    )
}

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.compref = React.createRef();
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        const height = this.compref.current.clientHeight;
        //which will be undefined --- No more!
        console.log('height: ', height);
    }
    
    onCompRef = (ref) => {
      this.compref.current = ref;
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Comp onRef={this.onCompRef} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Comp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}> some other stuff here </div>
));

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.compref = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const height = this.compref.clientHeight;
        console.log("hieght", height);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Comp ref={(el) => this.compref = el} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Could you try this way. Hope it helps. Please refer forward refs https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html